# Ag-Grid Angular Tree Data with Group Header

Tags: angular, tree, ag-grid, hierarchy

I am trying to adapt the Ag-Grid Org Hierarchy Tree Data example to my application.  Here is what I have so far:  https://plnkr.co/edit/rfK0uqKPPWJig7dx

```
    var rowData = [
  {  ID: 1,
    Path: '1/1', // [Group: 1, ID: 1]
    GroupID: 1,
    GroupName: 'Group 1',
    Name: '1. Row A'
  },
  {  ID: 2,
    Path: '1/2',
    GroupID: 1,
    GroupName: 'Group 1',
    Name: '2. Row B'
  },
  {  ID: 3,
    Path: '1/2/3', //[Group: 1, Parent: 2, ID: 3]
    GroupID: 1,
    GroupName: 'Group 1',
    Name: '2.1 Row C'
  },
  {  ID: 4,
    Path: '2/4',
    GroupID: 2,
    GroupName: 'Group 2',
    Name: '3. Row D'
  },
  {  ID: 5,
    Path: '2/4/5',
    GroupID: 2,
    GroupName: 'Group 2',
    Name: '3.1. Row E'
  },
  {  ID: 6,
    Path: '3/6',
    GroupID: 3,
    GroupName: 'Group 3',
    Name: '5. Row F'
  }
]

var gridOptions = {
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  components: {
    simpleCellRenderer: getSimpleCellRenderer()
  },
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'Path' ,
      headerName: 'Name',
      cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
      cellRendererParams: {
        suppressPadding: true,
        suppressCount: true,
        innerRenderer: 'simpleCellRenderer',
      },     
    },
  ],
  rowData: rowData,
  treeData: true,
  animateRows: true,
  groupDefaultExpanded: -1, 
  getDataPath: function(data) {
    return [data.Path.split('/')];
  },
};

// wait for the document to be loaded, otherwise
// ag-Grid will not find the div in the document.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // lookup the container we want the Grid to use
  var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

  // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
  new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
});

function getSimpleCellRenderer() {
  function SimpleCellRenderer() { }

  SimpleCellRenderer.prototype.init = function (params) {
    const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');

// this obviously needs to be different as there are multiple levels
    if(params.node.group) {
      tempDiv.innerHTML = params.data.GroupName;
    } else {
      tempDiv.innerHTML = params.data.Name;
    }
    
    this.eGui = tempDiv.firstChild;
  };
  SimpleCellRenderer.prototype.getGui = function () {
    return this.eGui;
  };
  return SimpleCellRenderer;
}
```

My path is major group id + tree hierarchy path.  GroupID/ParentRow/ParentRow/Row for example.  I'd like it to display in one grid column as

Group 1
  Parent Row 1
    Parent Row 2
      Item 6
Group 2
  Item 1
  Item 2
  Parent Row 3
    Item 3

As you can see, I have not gotten it to use the Path to group properly.  Also, in another example where I was able to get it to group by GroupID, I could not figure out how to display GroupName instead of GroupID.  So any information on that, would be helpful.  It seems like all of the examples I have found are using the Name to do the hierarchy but this will not work for my application.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of your question, the problem with the tree data view is in this line:

```
getDataPath: function(data) {
    return [data.Path.split('/')];
  },
```

Here you are returning an array within another one. To solve this, remove the brackets and return the result of split directly:

```
getDataPath: function(data) {
    return data.Path.split('/');
  },
```

For the second part, you can use the value of 'GroupName' to construct the hierarchy, for example:

```
  [...]
  {  ID: 4,
    Path: 'Group 2/3. Row D',
    GroupID: 2,
    GroupName: 'Group 2',
    Name: '3. Row D'
  },
  {  ID: 5,
    Path: 'Group 2/3.1. Row E',
    GroupID: 2,
    GroupName: 'Group 2',
    Name: '3.1. Row E'
  },
  [...]
```